# How to get total value in Pie Chart in AppDynamics

Tags: appdynamics

I created a Dashboard in AppDynamics that has 3 pie charts for calls per minute by Tier.
The pie charts display fine.  But I would like to total all of the value in the pie chart to have a grand total.
[image]

I would like to display the total of 1332 somewhere in the pie chart.
If that is not possible, how to create a widget that sums these tiers?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing I found within the pie chart widget that sums the values.
But I created another widget that sums this data and placed it below.
[image]